# How to select options based on field value not on ng-model object

Tags: angularjs

So basically I have  the following select box defined :

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<span  class="nullable">
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
    <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
  </select>
</span><br/>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Reinitialize array" ng-click="switchModel()"/>
</div>
```

And the following controller:

```
  angular.module('selectExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
  ];
  $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
  $scope.colorsB = [
     {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
  ];
  $scope.switchModel = function () {
    $scope.colors =  $scope.colorsB;
  };
  };

}]);
```

The problem I have is how to select the option contained in the `$scope.myColor` as the default option once the array `$scope.colors` is being reinitialized?

The plunker code is here : http://plnkr.co/edit/50TVcrlxJHVH9kdEZljc?p=preview

Comment: The value is looking at the .name property, so change it to $scope.colors[2].name and it should work. :)

Comment: Or you could change the ngOptions to ng-options="color as color.name for color in colors".

Comment: The thing is that I need the ng-model to reference the object $scope.colors[2], for other reasons, not presentence in this example

Comment: Option 2 should work for you then. Right now your $scope.myColor will save the name of the color, not the color object. By specifiying "color as color.name... you tell it to save the entire color object, but display the name.

Comment: It doesn't work : http://plnkr.co/edit/oNNzhlLy5fOvnFF2WjFm?p=preview

Comment: Looked like it worked to me? Do you mean the reinitialize part? In that case the "red" object is different (memory address), so you just have to write $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2] in your reinitialize function.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set the select value after initialization, without explicitly writing   $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2] in my re initialization (The code i have is much more complex than the example i provided). I was hoping to find a way of doing this based on the objects values/ content.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **switchModel** function , again update the model like below.

```
 $scope.switchModel = function () {
        $scope.colors =  $scope.colorsB;
        $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2];
      };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for something that will select the option based on the current  $scope.myColor field values without having to reinitialize the  $scope.myColor too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.switchModel = function () {
         $scope.colors =  $scope.colorsB;
         //Reinit Your $scope.myColor
         $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2];
    };
```

Comment: Not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for something that will select the option based on the current  $scope.myColor field values without having to reinitialize the  $scope.myColor too.